# Set the environment variable for RHEL 7.3 for root user

Tags: bash, redhat, rhel7

I managed to set the environment variable for my user imin by editing the `.bash_profile` under folder `/home/imin` and added the path to my php 71 bin. Now when I run `echo $PATH` it shows the changes that I made, but now I need to do the same for my root.

If I run `echo $PATH` under my user imin, it returns
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/imin/.local/bin:/home/imin/bin:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin`

So all is fine and dandy. But for my user root, I tried adding the line `/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin` at `/root/.bash_profile` and `/etc/skel/.bash_profile` but when I tried running `echo $PATH` it doesn't show the changes that I made. Instead it just show `/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`.

And since I couldn't get my rh-php71 bin inside my root PATH variable, I can't run php.

I have tried `find |grep .bash_profile` and it just return

```
./etc/skel/.bash_profile
./root/.bash_profile
```

and other folders under `/home/`.

So where should I actually edit to have my root's PATH updated?

Thanks

Update:
Also added the line `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin"` to `/root/.bashrc` as per Aroly7's answer below, but it still doesn't show in ECHO $PATH.

Here's my `/root/.bashrc` now:

```
# .bashrc

# User specific aliases and functions

alias rm='rm -i'
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

export PATH="$PATH:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin"
```

Comment: Maybe redundant: but updates to environment files don't take effect in your current session, you need to either log out & back in again, or source the environment file manually  (with a single dot followed by a space and the (path to) the file with environment settings i.e.  `. /root/.bashrc` ) 

Also how you become root changes (if and) how and which files will be sourced too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it in /root/.bashrc

`export PATH="$PATH:/opt/rh/rh-php71/root/usr/bin"`

But maybe consider creating links to /usr/sbin

Comment: Already added (please see my updated question above), but it still doesn't show in echo $PATH. Btw what do you mean by `maybe consider creating links to /usr/sbin` ? Sorry I'm a total noob in this unix linux thingy

Comment: did you call `reset` or logout/login?

Comment: Thanks, working after I logout and login again

Answer (score 0):

How do you become root? Do you login as root, or do you use `su`?
If you use `su`, try `su -` instead.